# SoftwareCode in SMS_InstalledSoftware

Tags: sccm

I'm trying to know product code of a installed application using SMS_InstalledSoftware class but it is giving "SoftwareCode" which normalized productcode. What is this normalized product code?

I have tried to fetch productcode as per SMS_installedSoftware ("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/develop/reference/core/clients/client-classes/sms_installedsoftware-client-wmi-class") but when I am executing this I am not getting productcode. I'm getting softwarecode.

```
(gwmi -namespace "root\cimv2\sms" -class SMS_InstalledSoftware |where-Object  {$_.Softwarecode -like "*%ProductCode GUID%*"}).Productversion
```

Product Code GUID is not same as software code

Comment: What version of SCCM are you using?  2007, 2012, Current Branch?

Comment: @Paul SCCM 2012.

Comment: in that WMI class their term SoftwareCode is the same as ProductCode. The "normalization" they do just means the product code has all lowercase character.  The Windows Installer (MSI) engine isn't case sensitive so using lowercase should work.  There is also an additional class with SCCM 2012 in the ROOT\ccm\CIModels namespace called "CCM_MSIProduct" that only has Product Code, ProductName, and Product Version (also an UpgradeCode property but its always blank).  Maybe revise the question to let us know what you're looking to accomplish so we can better assist.  Cheers.